# Deluge-web is running, nmap shows port 8112 is open, but cannot access webui

Tags: server, bittorrent, deluge

So I have not used deluge in a few years but wanted to set it back up recently.  I (mostly) followed the steps in the [guide here][1], but I made the 'deluge' user part of my existing 'media' group that also has users for my *arr stack of apps.  Everything worked perfect upon install.  I snatched some torrents and went about my week.

I came back a few days later to snatch again, and I **cannot** access the webui.  Here are my details.

Ubuntu Server 22.04.2
I have router DHCP setting the server to 10.0.0.5 and can access all my other programs on various ports there via LAN and WAN using duckdns.org (great free service)

Here is the config file for the deluge-web service at /etc/systemd/system/deluge-web.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Web Interface
Documentation=man:deluge-web
After=deluged.service
Wants=deluged.service

[Service]
Type=simple
UMask=027

ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluge-web -d

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Systemctl shows the necessary services are running
deluge-web:

```
user@server:~$ systemctl status deluge-web.service
● deluge-web.service - Deluge Bittorrent Client Web Interface
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/deluge-web.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/deluge-web.service.d
             └─user.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-05-17 23:39:25 EDT; 1 week 1 day ago
       Docs: man:deluge-web
   Main PID: 880 (deluge-web)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9257)
     Memory: 26.2M
        CPU: 1min 29.395s
     CGroup: /system.slice/deluge-web.service
             └─880 deluge-web "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

May 17 23:39:25 server systemd[1]: Started Deluge Bittorrent Client Web Interface.
user@server:~$
```

deluged:

```
user@server:~$ systemctl status deluged.service
● deluged.service - LSB: Start or stop the Deluge BitTorrent daemon.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/deluged; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2023-05-17 23:39:25 EDT; 1 week 1 day ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
        CPU: 7ms

May 17 23:39:22 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start or stop the Deluge BitTorrent daemon....
May 17 23:39:25 server deluged[776]:  * Starting Deluge BitTorrent Daemon deluged
May 17 23:39:25 server deluged[776]:    ...done.
May 17 23:39:25 server systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start or stop the Deluge BitTorrent daemon..
```

I will allow that I have never understood what **active (exited)** means, but I know when I connect to the deluge webui, I have to first click the "Start Daemon" button to launch the daemon on 127.0.0.1, so that doesn't *seem* problematic to me, but idk ‍♀️

nmap shows ports are up:

```
user@server:~$ nmap -p0- -v -A -T4 10.0.0.5
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-26 14:03 EDT
NSE: Loaded 151 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 14:03
Completed NSE at 14:03, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 14:03
Completed NSE at 14:03, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 14:03
Completed NSE at 14:03, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 14:03
Scanning 10.0.0.5 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 14:03, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 14:03
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 14:03, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 14:03
Scanning optiserver990 (10.0.0.5) [65536 ports]
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 8080/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 139/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 8989/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 8181/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 8112/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 32400/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 8686/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 7878/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Discovered open port 10000/tcp on 10.0.0.5
Completed Connect Scan at 14:03, 2.19s elapsed (65536 total ports)
```

But I **DO** notice a couple possible red flags ... Such as this one

```
Initiating Service scan at 14:03
Scanning 12 services on optiserver990 (10.0.0.5)
WARNING: Service 10.0.0.5:8112 had already soft-matched rtsp, but now soft-matched sip; ignoring second value
Completed Service scan at 14:04, 95.93s elapsed (12 services on 1 host)
```

I do **not** know what the warning means, but that is the port deluge is using.

Also, the service scan shows a 400 Bad Request error...

```
8112/tcp  open  ssl/rtsp
| fingerprint-strings:
|   GenericLines:
|     HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
|   GetRequest:
|     HTTP/1.0 200 OK
|     Server: TwistedWeb
|     Date: Fri, 26 May 2023 18:03:45 GMT
|     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
|     Content-Length: 2284
|     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
|     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
|     <head>
|     <title>Deluge WebUI 2.1.1</title>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge.png"/>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-32.png"/>
|     <!-- For Chrome, Android, iOS and Windows touch shortcuts: -->
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-192.png"/>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="512x512" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-512.png"/>
|     <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
|     href="/icons/deluge-apple-1
|   HTTPOptions:
|     HTTP/1.0 200 OK
|     Server: TwistedWeb
|     Date: Fri, 26 May 2023 18:03:50 GMT
|     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
|     Content-Length: 2284
|     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
|     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
|     <head>
|     <title>Deluge WebUI 2.1.1</title>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge.png"/>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-32.png"/>
|     <!-- For Chrome, Android, iOS and Windows touch shortcuts: -->
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-192.png"/>
|     <link rel="icon" sizes="512x512" type="image/png"
|     href="/icons/deluge-512.png"/>
|     <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
|_    href="/icons/deluge-apple-1
|_rtsp-methods: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=Deluge Daemon
| Issuer: commonName=Deluge Daemon
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2023-05-11T21:34:33
| Not valid after:  2026-05-10T21:34:33
| MD5:   611a 2dd4 3865 7fd8 0fe9 8fef fffb c173
|_SHA-1: 0859 0466 3b0d 5e1b 3e20 5a53 2861 7c95 c336 ba3f
```

So clearly I am missing SOMETHING but I am not experienced enough to figure it out on my own.  Appreciate any and all attempts at help